# Trying to prove that cardinality of Borel $\sigma$-algebra is the cardinality of the continuum

Tags: measure-theory, set-theory, solution-verification, borel-sets, transfinite-induction

I am trying to prove that the cardinality of the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}$ equipped with the standard topology is $c$, where $c=|\mathbb{R}|$ is the cardinality of the continuum.

**My attempt**

The Borel $\sigma$-algebra is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing the open sets of $\mathbb{R}$ in the standard topology. Since every open set of $\mathbb{R}$ is the countable disjoint union of open intervals, it follows that $\mathcal{B}=\sigma(\mathcal{C})$ where $\sigma(\mathcal{C})$ is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\mathcal{C}$ where $\mathcal{C}$ is the set of all open intervals of $\mathbb{R}$.

It is clear to me that we should proceed to prove the result by constructing the Borel $\sigma$-algebra, but it is here where I run into some problems/misunderstandings:

Let us start with the set of all open intervals $(a,b)$. Denote by $B_0$ this collection. Now, for a successor ordinal $\alpha$ (with predecessor $\alpha-1$), let $B_{\alpha}$ be the closure of $B_{\alpha-1}$ with regards to complementation, and countable union (including the subsets obtained via complementation). For the case where $\alpha$ is a limit ordinal, let $B_{\alpha}$ be the union of all previous sets constructed in this manner. Terminate at the first uncountable ordinal ($\omega_1$).

We want to show this is a $\sigma$-algebra. So, we need to show that the constructed $\mathcal{B}$ which is the union of all the collections $B_i$ we constructed in the above manner contains $\emptyset, \mathbb{R}$, and is closed under complementation/countable unions.

Clearly $\mathbb{R}\in\mathcal{B}$ since $\mathbb{R}=\bigcup\limits_{q\in\mathbb{Q}}(q,q+1)$. Also, $\emptyset\in\mathcal{B}$ since it is the complement of $\mathbb{R}$ (in particular, this is because it would have been added in the second iteration of the induction as per the process outlined above).

Next we show closure under complementation. Let $A\in\mathcal{B}$. then $A\in B_{\alpha}$ for some ordinal $\alpha$. Since every ordinal has an immediate successor, we have that $A^c\in B_{\alpha+1}\subseteq\mathcal{B}$ as desired. Showing closure under countable unions is identical. It remains to show that the generated collection is precisely the Borel $\sigma$-algebra, $\text{Bor}$. Since every open set is added in the second induction step (every open set is a disjoint countable union of open intervals), we have clearly that  $\text{Bor}\subseteq\mathcal{B}$. As well, every open interval is in $\text{Bor}$, so under closure, $\text{Bor}$ must contain all of $\mathcal{B}$.

Now, the cardinality of the collection of all open intervals is $c$. It remains to show that at each stage in the induction we never add more than $c$ things, and the result will follow. In the complementation step we clearly only add $c$ more things, and $c+c=c$. In the union step we add only the countable Cartesian product of sets having cardinality $c$ many element, but it is well known that this has cardinality at most $c$ again. So clearly at every induction step we add no more than $c$ many elements, which gives us that $|B_{\alpha}|=c$ for every ordinal $\alpha<\omega_1$.

To construct $\mathcal{B}$ we take the union of these sets each with cardinality $c$. But the $c$-union of cardinality $c$ sets again has cardinality $c$ and the proof is complete.

> Does this proof sound about right? Do you think I need any more details? Is there maybe a nicer way to word certain things (I feel as if I got a bit hand-wavy towards the end)?

Comment: If $\mathrm{Bor}\subseteq\mathcal{B}$ and $|\mathcal{B}|=\mathfrak c$, then $|\mathrm{Bor}|\leq\mathfrak c$ so you don't actually care whether they are equal or not as $\sigma$-algebras (though they are)

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti Good point! Is the rest okay as far as process goes?

Comment: You say closure under finite unions is identical... did you mean countable unions? (Finite unions won't cut it, unless I'm missing something.) Closure under countable unions is a bit more complicated in my estimation... not super hard but enough to warrant its own argument.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen yup. I fixed that typo. And ah. I see why it's more difficult. If we were dealing with finite unions then we could simply pick the largest ordinal indexing the sets, but here there might not be such a maximal index.

Comment: @quanticbolt Yep, you see how to make it work despite that?

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen I'm not too familiar with ordinal arithmetic, but could we maybe union all the collections containing sets in the countable union and somehow define some kind of limit ordinal?

Comment: @quantibolt Yes, that will work. The one thing that could go wrong is that maybe these levels are unbounded in $\omega_1$ so there’s no level above them. But it can be shown that the limit of countably many countable ordinals is always countable.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen do you know where I could find a proof of that?

Comment: @quanticbolt It will be in any place that treats uncountable ordinals I think, but I don't know of anywhere specifically. The easiest way to see it is that a countable ordinal is a countable set, and a limit of ordinals is their union, so the limit is a countable union of countable sets, hence countable.